# S3 acknowledgement after writes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Question: S3 sends write acknowledgement after successfully finished writing to S3? Or after writing partially? I tried to google i but I could not find answer.

According to this Doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

> Amazon S3 never adds partial objects; if you receive a success
>   response, Amazon S3 added the entire object to the bucket.

Is this mean we get success we get acknowledgement after fully writing to S3?

Comment: yes, you will get the response only when the file is fully written to S3 or any error during write.

Comment: It really can't be expressed any more clearly than it is expressed in the documentation you cited.  A successful write is a complete write. An upload that fails in progress is not committed to the bucket and is discarded.  What problem are you trying to solve?